# SQL how to assign table to variable with case when

Tags: sql-server

I have problem where I have 3 tables with date single date column. I need to assign one of these to variable to use as a filter later on in my query. Example will clear this one.

```
CREATE TABLE #missing_days (trade_date DATE)  
INSERT INTO #missing_days (trade_date) VALUES ('2022-04-10'), ('2022-04-09')

CREATE TABLE #all_days (trade_date DATE)  
INSERT INTO #all_days (trade_date) VALUES ('2022-04-12'), ('2022-04-11'), ('2022-04-10'), ('2022-04-09')

CREATE TABLE #one_day (trade_date DATE)  
INSERT INTO #one_day (trade_date) VALUES ('2022-04-12')
```

Now I have declared parameter to tell me what I would like to run

```
DECLARE @what_to_run VARCHAR(10) = 'ALL' --ALL run all dates, MISSING run only missing dates, ONE run only one day
```

Now depending what value `@what_to_run` has I need to use correct table in simple WHERE clause later on.

My idea was something like this:

```
DECLARE @Dates_to_run TABLE
(trade_date DATE)

SET @Dates_to_run = CASE WHEN @what_to_run = 'ALL' THEN (SELECT * FROM #all_days) 
                         WHEN @what_to_run = 'MISSING' THEN (SELECT * FROM #missing_days)  
                         ELSE (SELECT * FROM #one_day) END
```

but haven't had much success with it.

Expected result would be that when `@what_to_run = 'ALL'` I would have table with those dates from `#all_days` to use in simple query such as

```
SELECT * 
FROM dt
WHERE trade_date IN (SELECT trade_date FROM @Dates_to_run)
```

I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking here. Expected results will help us help you.

Comment: I tried to give idea what I'm expecting. But simply depending on value of @what_to_run, I would like to assign correct table to variable to use later on.

Comment: What do you mean by assign the correct table to a variable? You *can't* assign tables to a variable; that doesn't make sense.

Comment: ok, I thought that there would be away to fill TABLEVARIABLE this way, but assumed wrong.

Comment: You don't `SET` a table variable, you **`INSERT`** into it; it's a `table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must insert into your table variable, maybe this is what you want ?

```
declare @what_to_run varchar(20) = 'all' 

DECLARE @Dates_to_run TABLE (trade_date DATE)


if @what_to_run = 'ALL'
begin 
     insert into @Dates_to_run
     select * from #all_days 
end
else if @what_to_run = 'MISSING'
begin
     insert into @Dates_to_run
     SELECT * FROM #missing_days
end
else
begin
     insert into @Dates_to_run
     SELECT * FROM #one_day
end

select * from @Dates_to_run
```

Note that this will only work if the table #all_days, @missing_days and #one_day only have one column and it must be of the datatype DATE

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Union` and `WHERE condition` and `Subquery` by `changing variable` to get your desired result

```
DECLARE @what_to_run VARCHAR(10) = 'ALL'
DECLARE @Dates_to_run TABLE
(trade_date DATE)
INSERT INTO @Dates_to_run 
SELECT trade_date FROM 
(SELECT *,'ALL' AS V FROM #all_days
UNION 
SELECT *,'MISSING'  AS V  FROM #missing_days
UNION 
SELECT *,'Oneday'  AS V   FROM #one_day) T
WHERE @what_to_run=T.V
```